# Вывод новостей из базы в таблицу

Tags: php, html

Есть таблица шириной 700px: 5 строк, 10 ячеек (две колонки по 5 новостей). Если новостей в базе меньше 5 или 5, то мы заполняем новостями только левую колонку, если больше, например, 6, то начинает заполняться правая колонка. Как это реализовать? Картинки для наглядности

5 новостей

[image]

6 новостей

[image]

7 новостей

[image]

- Элемент списка

Answer (score 2):

Я так понял, что вам надо раcкидать новости именно внутри таблицы - < table >

```
$news = array(
'Новость 1',
'Новость 2',
'Новость 3',
'Новость 4',
'Новость 5',
'Новость 6',
'Новость 7',
'Новость 8',
'Новость 9',
'Новость 10',
'Новость 11'
);
$newsArr = array_chunk(array_reverse($news),5);
$tbl = '<table border="1"><tr>';
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
    for($k = 0; $k < count($newsArr); $k++){
        $tbl .= '<td>'.$newsArr[$k][$i].'</td>';
    }
    $tbl .= '</tr><tr>';
}
$tbl .= '</tr></table>';
echo $tbl;
```

P.S. Функция **array_reverse()** вам, я так думаю, что не нужна, т.к. вытакиваете из БД записи уже с сортировкой DESC.

И еще забыл добавить, что для чистоты процесса, можно "выровнять" размер массива, где элементов будет меньше пяти, но это на ваше усмотрение. В общем, в итоге, [получаем вот такие пирожки с котятами](http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/emj-6t5). (перейдя по ссылке, жмём **F9**)

Answer (score 1):

Есть пара вариантов на памяти:

1.Отказаться от таблицы в верстке и сделать чтото в таком духе:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='left'>
          <div>новость 6</div>
          <div>новость 5</div>
          <div>новость 4</div>
          <div>новость 3</div>
          <div>новость 2</div>
     </div>
     <div class='right'>
          <div>новость 1</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

и заполнять соответственно примерно таким образом:

```
$counter=0;
foreach($reversed_news_list as $news){
   if (counter<5){
       left_block;...
   }else{
       right_block;..
   }
}
```

2.Заранее разбить список сообщений на 2 части (левая и правая колонка):
 и так же вывести через `foreach`

Comment: А дальше как?))

Answer (score 1):

Получаем массив новостей, в зависимости от количества рендерим партиал

Comment: foreach($reversed_news_list as $news){
   if (counter<5){
       left_block;...
если новостей будет больше, то left_block он ведь не заполнит

Comment: не много не так, передаем из контроллера массив, во вьюхе смотрим на количество и рендерим шаблон в зависимости от количества, а в шаблонах только разметка с циклом

Answer (score 1):

В css3 есть приятное свойство: [column-count](http://htmlbook.ru/css/column-count). Но для не поддерживающих это свойство браузеров придется писать скрипт совместимости.